# Flutter: Get custom properties from Window Object

Tags: flutter, web, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Web3 Flutter website (just to learn flutter).

I would like to programmatically know if there is an extension installed or not (Metamask in this case).
In the documentation they say that I can check if Metamask is installed by checking if `window.ethereum != undefined` (in JS).

Obviously, I don't have this property in the Window object of flutter..
Is there a variable that list all unknown properties or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3

there is a property that you can use as

```
    / `Ethereum.isSupported` is the same as `ethereum != null`
if (ethereum != null) {
  try {
    // Prompt user to connect to the provider, i.e. confirm the connection modal
    final accs = await ethereum!
        .requestAccount(); // Get all accounts in node disposal
    accs; // [foo,bar]
  } on EthereumUserRejected {
    print('User rejected the modal');
  }
}
```